# How do I demo my android application over the web?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I am working on an android application and I need to demo the app on a machine that is not my development machine.  It actually sits in our conference room, is hooked up to a projector, and we demo our other products over GoToMeeting with it.  I am curious as to the best way to demo my application to potential clients.

The easiest way I see this happening (other than pushing it onto my phone) is to install the SDK on the demo machine, and then push my APK to the AVD using the command line (a batch file if possible).

How would I go about pushing my APK to the AVD?  I have seen (and have done) a manual push to an actual android device, but never to the virtual device (other than when eclipse does it).

While this is an acceptable approach I am curious how others demo their applications to remote users/clients/bosses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push you apk to avd on the development machine...and do remote desktop from you conference room machine to development machine and demo you application on the projector.

Installing command will be same for both AVD and real device.

Answer (score 3):

Well when it's my turn to do a presentation, I will opt one of the following 2 options:

1. Make a swf flash presentation of application by demontrsting and touching each aspect of application by the Jing dektop tool. You can grab it from link http://www.techsmith.com/jing/
2. I will use Teamviewer and do a RDS (Remote Desktop Session) with my machine.

Answer (score 2):

`adb install -r path/to/apk/file.apk` should work to install an APK to a running phone connected via USB with development-mode enabled, or to an emulator. Should work on any machine with the Android SDK tools installed (you may need to add the folder for the SDK's tools folder before the `adb` command if that folder isn't on your machine's `PATH`, though).

Answer (score 1):

Some devices (HTC Evo, Droid X) have HDMI output, so maybe a solution lies here. You can purchase capture devices for about $200 that might show an HDMI input stream in a nice window, that would work with GoToMeeting.

Comment: These types of apps may be on the way. See http://forum.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-rooting-roms-hacks/63799-fullhdmi-official-fullhdmi-beta-discussion.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AppSurfer](http://www.appsurfer.com) You can simply upload your app and share a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can install to a phone or emulator by

```
${android_sdk}\platform-tools\adb install c:\directory\app.apk
```

and uninstall by

```
${android_sdk}\platform-tools\adb uninstall com.my.package.app
```

Only issue I would worry about is the instability and bad performance of the emulator. In my experience the
emulator seems to experience random crashes and runs very slowly (understably) compared to a real device.
You may want to try something canned using a screencast that you speak to, or also bring some actual devices
so the clients can play with the app in a real environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good tools for testing you application. If you don't get one then just allow the first few to use it free and they write review over it. That should serve as a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I often have to demo to clients remotely.  I prefer to demo on a real device, not an AVD, and was a little stuck on a simple way to do this, until I came across [Android Projector.](http://code.google.com/p/android-projector/)

Simply unzip and run, and it projects your device's screen to your machine's monitor.
You can then share your desktop, RDS, Webex, whatever...